# Gstreamer Pipeline Issues

Tags: gstreamer

My current gstreamer (1.18.4) pipeline that "works" is this

```
appsrc format=time is-live=true do-timestamp=true name=src ! application/x-rtp ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink max-size-time=300000000000  muxer=mp4mux muxer-factory=mp4mux muxer-properties="properties,streamable=true,reserved-moov-update-period=1000000000" location=video%02d.mp4
```

I say kind of works because it does produce the files and they do work for my need but on Chrome JSVideoPlayer it produces an error 4 media issue and also produces these gstreamer warnings

```
 FIXME                default gstutils.c:4025:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<src:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3384:gst_base_sink_default_event:<sink> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:3076:gst_qt_mux_start_file:<mp4mux0> Robust muxing requires reserved-moov-update-period to be set
 FIXME             aggregator gstaggregator.c:1365:gst_aggregator_aggregate_func:<mp4mux0> Subclass should call gst_aggregator_selected_samples() from its aggregate implementation.
```

Ive tried so many combinations of adding groupIds, StreamIds and the moov time settings but none of them seem to have any effect.

How can I change my pipeline to remove this warnings?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about this one warning and the three fixme's -- the latter, I think, are just annotations from the developers for things they'd like to improve, but don't present a problem.

Comment: Thank I think you are right, ive tried so much but just cant remove the errors.

Comment: The thing that has driven me to try and remove these error is that for some reason between my working test environment to product I am seeing the error "VideoJS: Error: (CODE: 4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media"

The only difference appears to be test env is using Gst 1.18.4 and ffmpeg version 4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1 Where production is using the latest on both. 

Yet production MP4s from the pipeline have this error when viewed on chrome but not on firefox. Test env doesn't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

Higher framerate/profile/bitrate/level may cause this error.
I am suspecting the decoder capability here. Can you check if making video source as H.264 baseline profile helps you. then you need to check what profile and level is used in the SPS and PPS

Comment: Upgrading all the systems involved in encoding and decoding to Gstreamer 1.20 resolved the Error 4 issues